# Where the data is stored in HDFS? Is there a way to change where its stored?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm a novice. I have a 3-Node Cluster. The Name Node, Job Tracker and Secondary Name Node are running in one node and two data nodes (HData1, HData2) in the other two cluster. If I store data from my local system to HDFS, how to find in which node it resides? Is there a way I can explicitly specify in which data node it has to be stored?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes you can find it using **hadoop fsck path**
2. you can refer below links

[how does hdfs choose a datanode to store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129599/how-does-hdfs-choose-a-datanode-to-store) 
[How to explicilty define datanodes to store a particular given file in HDFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810845/how-to-explicilty-define-datanodes-to-store-a-particular-given-file-in-hdfs)

Comment: Can you please post an example of HDFS FSCK command that shows the location of file in which data node it exists?